# Determine SMB shares I have read and/or write access to

Tags: smb, shared-folders

For a series of targets (IPs), Id like to determine which SMB shares my account has no access to, which it has read access to, and which it has read/write access to.

Currently I am using smbclient. The command I run first is

```
smbclient -L [targetIP] -U [user] -p 445
```

This gives me a list of shares. For example;

```
        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
        C$              Disk      Default share
        IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
        print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
        MySecrets       Disk
```

I then can connect to a file share with this command

```
smbclient //[target]/[name_of_share_from_list] -U [user] -p 445
```

Which results in an SMB prompt. From the prompt I type `ls` and if I see files I know I have read access. I'm guessing I have to push a file to see if I have write access.

This is tedious. How do I automate this such that for the given list of targets, I get a list of all shares, and the level of access my account has to them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had much of the work already in place. Reading the man page for `smbclient` would have given you the `-c <command>` parameter, which can be used to provide one or more commands directly rather than interactively.

```
#!/bin/bash
username="DOMAIN\\USER"    # Double backslash
password="PASSWORD"        # For demonstration purposes only
hostname="TARGET_HOST"     # SMB hostname of target

cd "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"
touch tmp_$$.tmp           # Required locally to copy to target

smbclient -L "$hostname" -g -A <( echo "username=$username"; echo "password=$password" ) 2>/dev/null |
    awk -F'|' '$1 == "Disk" {print $2}' |
    while IFS= read -r share
    do
        echo "Checking root of share '$share'"

        if smbclient "//$hostname/$share/" "$password" -U "$username" -c "dir" >/dev/null 2>&1
        then
            status=READ

            # Try uprating to read/write
            if smbclient "//$hostname/$share/" "$password" -U "$username" -c "put tmp_$$.tmp ; rm tmp_$$.tmp" >/dev/null 2>&1
            then
                status=WRITE
            fi
        else
            status=NONE
        fi

        case "$status" in
            READ) echo "Well, $username has read access" ;;
            WRITE) echo "Yes, $username has write access" ;;
            *) echo "No, $username has no access" ;;
        esac
    done

rm -f tmp_$$.tmp
```

Comment: Ah i was wondering if id have to resort to a bash script like this. I havent written one yet but this may give me a good starting point. Can you edit this to output if i have read access only?

Comment: In addition to the check for write as well i mean

Comment: @n00b. You could change the second `echo` putting the message "$username has read-only access to the root of this share". Unless you are also scanning directories that you have no read access at all...

Comment: The later is the case. I dont know if I have read access, and would rather have the option to 'try writing' after knowing if I have read access first. In otherwords, tell me if I have read first, then tell me if I have write. Is that possible?

Comment: what does the read and write commands do exactly. I.e. i understand the dir command but what does ("dir" >/dev/null 2>&2)   do? similarly for the write portion I understand put and remove file, but when you do put tmp_$$.tmp" does that create a file with dollar signs if it doesnt exist?

Comment: `$$` is the current process identifier (number). You can see you shell's value with `echo $$` and it will match the entry in the first column of `ps -ef`

Comment: `2>&2` was a typo that I've changed to `2>&1`. The construct tells the shell to send everything intended for _stderr_ (channel 2) to _stdout_ (channel 1) instead. In this particular case I've already redirected _stdout_ to `/dev/null` so the net effect of `>/dev/null 2>&1` is that nothing is output from the command.

Comment: Hey I finally had a chance to test this, and it seems to be stuck/not running. the line it seems to get stuck on is the smbclient one (echo statements before that run just fine). help?

Comment: @n00b 1. You've set the three variables at the top of the script? 2. How exactly are you running the script?

Comment: @roaima I did. I saved it in a script.sh file, ran the chmod 755 script.sh command then am trying to execute ./script.sh but it just sits and sits. I added echo 'breadcrumbs' and the echos execute up until the smbclient line

Comment: did you have any luck getting it to run?

Comment: @n00b it worked for me when I wrote it. Which `smbclient` invocation hangs for you?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [SMBmap](https://github.com/ShawnDEvans/smbmap) can help you with this tastk. Its author developed it precisely for that purpose.

```
$  python smbmap.py -H [targetIP] -u [user] -P 445
[+] Finding open SMB ports....
[+] User SMB session establishd...
[+] IP: 192.168.0.4:445 Name: 192.168.0.4
        Disk                                                    Permissions
        ----                                                    -----------
        ADMIN$                                                  READ, WRITE
        C$                                                      READ, WRITE
        IPC$                                                    NO ACCESS
        TMPSHARE                                                READ, WRITE
```

You can use `--host-file` to pass a list of targets.

Internally, it tries to create a directory with a random name to check if we have write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as accepted answer but using **ansible**.  This can then be used for mounting as read-only or read-write.  (Which then makes other tools such as **mergerfs** work as expected when a union of filesystems is created)

```
- name: get available samba shares
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: "smbclient -L //{{ samba_ip }} -U % -g | grep Disk"
  register: samba_shares_raw

- name: extract samba shares
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    samba_shares: "{{ (samba_shares | default([])) + [ ( item | split('|') )[1] ] }}"
  loop: "{{ samba_shares_raw.stdout_lines }}"

- name: send a file to test ro / rw access
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/samba_client"
    state: touch

- name: test writeable samba
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: "smbclient -U % //{{ samba_ip }}/{{ item }} -c 'put samba_client'"
    chdir: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}"
  register: writeable_raw
  ignore_errors: true
  loop: "{{ samba_shares }}"

- name: extract writeable results
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    writeable: "{{ writeable | default({}) | combine({ item.item : not item.failed }) }}"
  loop: "{{ writeable_raw.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item }}"

- name: samba mount directories
  ansible.builtin.file:
    state: directory
    recurse: true
    path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/samba/{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ samba_shares }}"

- name: mount samba shares
  ansible.posix.mount:
    src: "//{{ samba_ip }}/{{ item }}"
    path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/samba/{{ item }}"
    fstype: cifs
    opts: "{{ 'rw' if writeable[item] else 'ro' }},guest,uid=1000,gid=1000"
    state: mounted
  loop: "{{ samba_shares }}"
  become: true
```